# Get index of Item in Loop to match against stored Indices

Tags: loops, flutter, dart

I have a scenario where I want to perform an action if a string in a list of string matches the index in a list of ints (Generated based on String list )

The below is some pseudo code to try and articulate what I am trying to achieve.

```dart
List<int> wordIndex = [1,3,5];
List<String> wordList = ['this', 'is','a', 'test', 'a'];

//Pseudo code
wordList.forEach(word)) {
 if (wordIndex item matches index of word) {
    do something;
  } else {
    od something else;
 }
}
```

it the `if (wordIndex item matches index of word)` where I am having a problem and would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know if the index of a word is contained in you `wordIndex` list, i.e. you want to get all `wordList` items with an index that is stored in `wordIndex`.

There are two approaches to this:

### Use [`Iterable.contains`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html)

In this case, we are simple checking if the current index is present in the `wordIndex` list.

```dart
for (var index = 0; index < wordList.length; index++) {
  if (wordIndex.contains(index)) {
    // do something
    return;
  }

  // do something else
}
```

### Loop through `wordIndex`

If you are just interested in the **matching items**, this approach is more reasonable.
Here, we loop through the index list and then simply get the matching elements in the `wordList`. However, you will not be able to take actions for the non-matching items:

```dart
for (final index in wordIndex) {
  final word = wordList[index];

  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `for` instead of `forEach`;

```
List<int> wordIndex = [1,3,5];
List<String> wordList = ['this', 'is','a', 'test', 'a'];

//Pseudo code
for (int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
  if (wordIndex.contains(i)) {
    do something;
  } else {
    od something else;
 }
}
```

Comment: It's funny how you get so used to the loop helper functions you forget the basics. Thanks for that.